# Custom Renderer - Add HTML tags

Tags: xpages, custom-renderer

I've read a lot of posts about custom renderers, but I can't seem to find, what I am looking for.

It is, again, about the combobox. XPages renders the combobox in read mode as a table and the custom renderers I've found, help to write out just the value of the field.

What I would like to do though, is to wrap the value in HTML input tags, so that in read mode, the Bootstrap styles are applied to it.

Is it possible to do that in a custom renderer and if so, how would I do that?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI - I believe there's already been 1 show on NotesIn9.com on custom renderers but there's another great one coming very soon.  Hopefully next week.  So maybe there will be good info in there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use a computed control when in read mode and have that control output the input tag you want? Hide the combobox in read mode and vice-versa?

Howard

Comment: Hello Howard, thank you for your response. Yes, that would be one way to do it and I thought about it. However, the idea of the custom renderer is very intriguing and I would love to learn more about it. It seems to be a very powerful option.